# Default value 1 is not returned when the default value is omitted

Tags: jmeter

Reporting against Jmeter 5.3 on Mac

Referred to the JMeter Functions and Variables documentation.
[___P function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

JMeter was started through command with following options

```
jmeter -Jgroup1.threads=7 -Jhostname1=www.realhost.edu
```

[image]

Default value is not set to 1 when it is omitted.

```
${__P(group1.loops,)}
```

Did not return 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P):

> Unlike the __property function, there is no option to save the value in a variable, and **if no default value is supplied, it is assumed to be 1**. The value of 1 was chosen because it is valid for common test variables such as loops, thread count, ramp up etc.

In your example, you have added a default value by using ',' after group1.loops, meaning default value is empty:

> ${__P(group1.loops,)}

To get 1, just use:

> ${__P(group1.loops)}

Disclaimer: This answer is Felix's one, I am just waiting for him to create the answer and will ask @Janesh to unaccept this one and accept Felix's one.

Comment: It is not a bug in the documentation. Your example used a default value and you got it back.

Use `${__P(group1.loops)}` Note the missing comma.

Comment: HiFelix,sorry my brain kind of bugged, can you add your answer, I’ll delete mine. Thanks